# Array with 1 million number

Tags: arrays, soap, soapui

We use Wizdler to get data. But we have to get data about 1 million person.
There is an alternative to search for only one or multiple.
We always writing ID here, one by one.
Our questions is, is there anyway to input 1 million number into here in one time?
We have also a list over all ID numbers too. Is that possible to input link to our files that has all numbers or we must write all number like that?

```xml
<int xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Arrays">123456</int>
<int xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Arrays">654321</int>
```

I have all Combination saved as text file. Looking like that.

0000000

0000001

0000002

0000003

etc...

Comment: When yo say the numbers are in file, how does it look like? i.e., the format of the data.

Comment: I have as text like that. Line by line.
0000000
0000001
0000002 etc...

Comment: A million lines? It is possible to do it using `groovy script` Full request sample would be helpful. If that is just that 1,2,3, it is even possible without your input text file.

Comment: Yes, it is 1 million line.

Comment: The problem is, we have only access to xmlns file, we use this chrome plugin Wizdler to get results. But it is to hard doing this process 1 million time, therefore want to do in one time instead doing that million time.

Comment: Based on the comment, just a basic question, Is this question related soapui?Do you have a wsdl file in first place? I do not know what you mean by `xmlns` file.

Comment: yeas I have wsdl file as link.

Comment: May be you can Import it into soapui and create a test case and try your request if not already and wanted to use soapui. By the way, are you ok with a solution to use Groovy Script from soapUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use a link to your file in that SOAP request. The SOAP request has to contain all the identifiers you want to retrieve. Also, one million of rows will be presumably too much for that web service and you will need to split them to multiple chunks.

To create a SOAP request with all the numbers, you can use a command to generate all the `int` elements. Then you can just use any text editor to wrap it into a SOAP envelope. This will give you the request you can send to the web service.

In Linux environment, the command to generate the lines will look like this (`identifiers.txt` is the name of your file with all the identifiers, `a` is the namespace alias for `http://schemas.microsoft.com/Arrays` that has to be defined beforehand):

```
awk '$0="<a:int>"$0"</a:int>"' identifiers.txt
```

The result will look like this:

```
<a:int>0000000</a:int>
<a:int>0000001</a:int>
<a:int>0000002</a:int>
<a:int>0000003</a:int>
```

You can also generate the whole request, not only the repetitive part of it. The following example assumes that operation name is `yourRequest` and it is in the namespace `yourNamespace`. The `int` elements are also not wrapped in any other element. You have to alter this to match your scenario:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "<Envelope xmlns=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n\t<Body>\n\t\t<yourRequest xmlns=\"yourNamespace\" xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/Arrays\">"}{print "\t\t\t<a:int>"$0"</a:int>"}END{print "\t\t</yourRequest>\n\t</Body>\n</Envelope>"}' identifiers.txt > request.xml
```

After executing the previous command, the `request.xml` will have the following content:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <yourRequest xmlns="yourNamespace" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Arrays">
            <a:int>0000000</a:int>
            <a:int>0000001</a:int>
            <a:int>0000002</a:int>
            <a:int>0000003</a:int>
        </yourRequest>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

For the SOAP envelope, I have used the namespace for SOAP 1.1 (`http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/`). If your service understands SOAP 1.2 only, change the namespace accordingly (`http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope`).

To call the web service, you can use `curl`:

```
curl -d "@request.xml"  "http://url/to/your/web/service" -H "Content-Type: text/xml"
```

Add `SOAPAction` HTTP header if your web service requires it. Also change the content type from `text/xml` for SOAP 1.1 to `application/soap+xml` for SOAP 1.2.

With all that being said, the final request with million numbers will have approximately 18 MB at least. Such huge request will most likely fail because of a maximum POST size limit or a timeout. To work around this, split the request into smaller requests.